# namedQuery - select field from superclass

Tags: hibernate, jpa, named-query

I've got a problem I couldn't find a sultion, yet. Hope you brains can give me a hint, though :)

The code below shows how it worked till now. But now I want to extend the SELECT by giving back the superColumn2 from the supperClass.

This is my superclass for my two subclasses:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class SuperClass extends MyEntity{

    @Column(name = "superColumn2", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String superColumn2;

    ...
}
```

subclass1:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UC_subClass1",
    columnNames = {"superColumn1", "superColumn2"}))
public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {

}
```

anyTable:

```
@Entity
public class TableX extends MyEntity {
    @Column(name = "columnX", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String columnX;

    @Column(name = "subClass1_id", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private SubClass1 subClass1_id;
}
```

and the named query:

```
SELECT tx.columnX, sc1.superColumn2
FROM TableX tx 
JOIN tx.subClass1_id sc1;
```

Error is: ***antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: sc1***

Hope you can give me a small hint.

Thanks a lot